# Real Time data graph

Tags: javascript, html, graph, javascript-framework

I would like to build a web-based real time data graph and i'm looking at the different options such as:

- Html5 canvas
- JS libraries with graph support such
  as Extjs

By real time i mean, either the client polling the web server say every second or using reverse ajax; the server pushes data to the client when available.

Can you please recommend any?

Comment: what is real time? Every Day, Hour, year, millisecond? What does the Graph show? Stock indexes, wheater, tornadoes, people locations?

Comment: it should be configurable, either the client polling the server say every second or through reverse ajax, the server pushes data to the client when available ...

Comment: you should check this post http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/five-apps/create-real-time-graphs-with-these-five-free-web-based-apps/

Comment: as for the readily-available service I would recommend http://plotti.co/ which is extremely simple to use - it deals with polling and all the stuff automatically, you even don't need any JS (disclaimer: I am the creator of plottico)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You may want to consider using [Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/), an open-source plotting library based on [jQuery](http://jquery.com).

I'm assuming that by real-time you mean that the graph will update automatically. The following is how your code would look like if you were to fetch and plot the data using AJAX polling at 1 second intervals:

```
function fetchData() {
   $.ajax({
      url:      'json_fetch_new_data.php',
      method:   'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      success:  function(series) {
         var data = [ series ];

         $.plot($('#placeholder'), data, options);
      }
   });

   setTimeout(fetchData, 1000);
}
```

Make sure to check out the following demo to see it in action (Click on the "Poll for Data" button):

- [Flot Examples - Updating graphs with AJAX](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/ajax.html)

For further information on Flot:

- [Flot Project Site](http://code.google.com/p/flot/)
- [Flot Examples](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/)
- [Other Flot Examples](http://www.midnightkite.com/flot/examples/)

Answer (score 16):

There is also [SmoothieCharts](http://smoothiecharts.org/) that is designed more for this use-case.

Comment: SmoothieCharts is great, although it only displays a short sliding window of the time series.  I have yet to find something that looks as good as SmoothieCharts but compresses the horizontal axis as the time series grows (thereby ensuring the full time series is always displayed, no matter how big it gets).

Comment: I tried Smoothiecharts, and it is just what we needed for real-time strip chart display of dynamic data.  Wow -- so easy to implement and works on FF Chrome IE.

Answer (score 5):

Other solution with design more nice and possibilities:

https://changelog.com/posts/rickshaw-realtime-javascript-graphing-library

example:
http://shutterstock.github.com/rickshaw/examples/extensions.html

code: 
https://github.com/shutterstock/rickshaw